# Pandas script work on computer - not on a secure server ("KeyError")?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, anaconda, keyerror

I have received a .xlsx file from a "costumer" that I need to parse into a certain way to get the information into a MySQL database.

The python script I have written (Pandas) are working like a charm on my own computer - but as soon as I transfer the script to the secure server where the real parsing has to happen, it returns a "KeyError" message.

I have been through numerous posts in here regarding "KeyError" in Pandas scripts without finding a solution that works.

Therefore, I hope that some of you may recognize this issue and know a solution that would work?

The test xlsx file I received looks like (yes, there is annoying spaces etc. - and they want to keep it that way):

```
'Rack Position', 'STUDY ID', 'Freeze-thaw cycles', 'New Rack Position', 'Project code'
A1, 92, 1, B2, '1,4'
A2, 93, 0, B3, 1
A3, 94, 1, B4, 1
```

It is an excel file, so the quotes around the names are not present. I just added those to make it more readable.

The "costumer" wants the following format with an additional info about the table:

```
studyid,count,field,value,table
92, 1, 'Rack Position', A1, table1
92, 1, 'New Rack Position', B2, table1
92, 1, 'Project code', 1
92, 1, 'Project code', 2
93, 0,  'Rack Position, 1
... and so on
```

I wrote this script, that works perfectly on my own computer:

```
import pandas as pd

# reading in the file (excel converted to csv, semicolon delimited to avoid errors with the "Project code" column)
df = pd.read_excel(/home/data/test.xlsx, sheet_name='ALL BOXES')

# rename STUDY ID to studyid and Freeze-thaw cycles to count
df = df.rename(columns={'STUDY ID': 'studyid', 'Freeze-thaw cycles': 'count'})

# splitting "Project code" based on comma into two columns (Project code1 and Project code2) -if more comma seperated
# values, this need to be changed to more columns
df = df.join(df['Project code'].str.split(',', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Project code1', 1:'Project code2'}))

# remove the now excessive "Project code" from the table
df = df.drop('Project code', 1)

# Split the dataframe based on Project code1 and Project code2
df1 = df[['Rack position', 'studyid', 'count', 'New Rack Position', 'Project code1']]
df2 = df[['Rack position', 'studyid', 'count', 'New Rack Position', 'Project code2']]

# rename Project code1 and Project code2 to Project code
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Project code1': 'Project code'})
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Project code2': 'Project code'})

# concatenate the dataframes based on "Project code"
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)

# remove Project code = 0
df = df[df['Project code'].notnull()]

# convert the data frame into the long format
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['studyid', 'count'], var_name='field', value_name='value')

# Change all NaNs to None
df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)

# creating new column with MySql table name
table = []
df['table'] = 'table1'

#save to file:
df.to_csv('filename.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

But on the secure server, it returns following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/data/sample.py", line 17, in <module>
df = df.join(df['Project code'].str.split(',', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Project code1', 1:'Project code2'}))
File: "/tools/anaconda2/4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py, line 2688, in _getitem_
return self._getitem_column(key)
File: "/tools/anaconda2/4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py, line 2695, in _getitem_column
return self._getitem_cache(key)
File: "/tools/anaconda2/4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py, line 2489, in _getitem_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
File: "/tools/anaconda2/4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py, line 4115, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File: "/tools/anaconda2/4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py, line 3080, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
File: "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File: "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File: "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File: "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Project code'
```

On the server, the script is run through python2.7 in an anaconda module (4.4.0). On my computer, the script has been written and tested in PyCharm (2018.2.2) with python2.7 (pandas ver. 0.23.4 and anaconda ver. 0.0.1.1).

Comment: immediately before the line `df = df.join(df['Project code'].str.split(...`, do `print(df.columns)` and run this on the secure server. What do you get?

Comment: You forgot to close a quote on line 17 around `'New Rack Position,`. Did you copy your script exactly?

Comment: asongtoruin: when I qsub the script with print(df.columns) (and commenting out the rest of the script) the same error comes up.
con: thank you for notifying me; the number of columns a much larger than here, so I simplified it here to illustrate the issue. In the real script, the quote is there (I will correct it right away in the problem description).

Comment: Yes, the same error will come up but it should also have printed a list of the frame columns just before the error

Comment: I finally got the "print" to work. It seems like there is an "u" in front of each column name. print(df.columns) results in: Index([    u'Box number',    u'studyid',   etc...])